# django channels authentication over script

Tags: python, django, authentication, websocket, channel

I have a Django Channel project and i want to connect to a Websocket over a script.

I am useing the code from the [example](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat)

as a python websocket-client I use [this](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)

I get the cookies from login in over script this is the result

```
'csrftoken': 'NGl4QuroPpp41zzsxODqdNv7UoaOmrNdbYc5H7AwzHajvLsUrHVJmwj7K1fdwBcC', 'sessionid': '5ccdsjby3g65xtltdppcdi0h8mmlr7h0
```

and I am using it the webclient like this

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/stream/",
                                on_message=self.on_message,
                                on_error=self.on_error,
                                on_close=self.on_close,
                                cookie=cookies)
    ws.on_open = self.on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

I don't know if the cookies are somehow wrong or I need to use anothe websocket client.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `WebsocketConsumer`? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: I am. If i wasn't clear. i want to connect over a external script which is separate from django and the WebsocketConsumer